# Reading different data types in database/file(File Handling in C++)

Tags: c++, database

I am doing an ATM exercise. In my database or ".txt" file I have the basic information.

```
0123456789 John Doe 0123 9000
```

The only thing I can find in the internet, reading a file in C++ is using `getline();`. It reads the file and stores it in a variable string. I have values like integer and float which I have to use.

- How do I store the values in my database to a different data type not
  just in one string?
- Or is there a way of cutting the string and store the the different values in a float or integer?
- Is there another way of reading? I am just new to C++ programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++,you can read file by "file stream":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string filename="test.txt";
    ifstream fin(filename);
    while (!fin.fail()){//read until end of file
        int a,d,e;
        string b,c;
        fin>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e;//That's a line
        cout<<a<<" "<<b<<" "<<c<<" "<<d<<" "<<e<<" \n";//show it on command line
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the stream can automatically ignore spaces, and read different data types

Answer (score 1):

You can use the libary `#include <fstream>`. Here's a code of what it will look like in your case. In "Text.txt" I copied and pasted your inputfile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main() {

    int firstNumber, thirdNumber, fourthNumber;
    string firstString, secondString;

    //Reading from a file
    ifstream file;
    file.open("Text.txt", ios::in);

    if (file.is_open()) {
        while (!file.eof()) {

            file >> firstNumber >> firstString >> secondString >> thirdNumber >> fourthNumber;
            cout << firstNumber << " " << firstString << " " << secondString << " " << thirdNumber << " " << fourthNumber << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "File did not open";
    }



    //Outputing to a file
    ofstream file2;
    file2.open("SecondText.txt", ios::out); // ios::out instead of ios::in

    if (file2.is_open()) {



        file2 << firstNumber << " " << firstString << " " << secondString << " " << thirdNumber << " " << fourthNumber;


        file2.close();

    }
    else {
        cout << "Problem with SecondText.txt";
    }

    return 0;

}
```

This code basically states that while open, and not at the end of the file, retrieve an Integer, String, String, Integer, and Integer, in that order for every line in that file.

If you have any questions just ask!

Comment: How about in writing, is it the same?

Comment: @guwop69 Writing to a file? If so give me a couple minutes to edit my answer to show you.  EDIT: I just updated my answer to output to a file

Comment: Thanks, now I have a problem in reading the file. Example I have a lot of lines of information on my .txt file. When I try getting the last information in the file it wont read. Is it because of the while loop?

Comment: The while loop says `while (not at end of file) {do this}`. Are you trying to get the last Line of the file, or last couple of integers in a line? Sorry I don't think I understood well.

Comment: I just tested my example above with a file with multiple lines and it worked for me. Can you get every other line besides the last? If so after the while loop you can hardcode a `file >> firstNumber >> firstString >> secondString >> thirdNumber >> fourthNumber;` after the `}`.

Comment: Just added a new question about the last line problem.

Comment: Yes I can get every line except the last one.

Comment: Oh okay, no prob! I'll go check the other question you made about it!

Comment: Stuck on this problem.